# Javascript Simple Puzzle

Tags: optimization, puzzle

How can you optimize the following JS statement :

```
obj.endDate = obj.status && (obj.status.length == 2 || (obj.status.length == 1 && obj.status[0] == 0)) ? undefined : obj.endDate;
```

where

`obj.status` is of array type and is allowed to take only the following values:

1. [1]
2. [0]
3. [1,0]
4. undefined

`obj.status` may or may not be be undefined.

Comment: Questions on how to improve working code are best asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you mean by optimize something like `how can i make this code easier to understand` then we have to better understand what you want to achieve. I understood the following of your code `if_Array_has_two_values or Array_has_one_value_and_it_is_zero` then set endDate to undefined. So i assume that there is a reason for doing so. If you can explain the logic behind this check than this probably helps to create some functions with meaning full names. What does it mean `(if obj.status == [0] or obj.status == [1,0])`  Does this mean something like `contract not terminated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't really optimizing it. The problem is that it is illegible. You or someone else will be grateful later when reading this code later to see it split up into some if/else or at least split it up a little with some clear naming.

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out the difference between optimisation and general cleanup. Could you show an example?